# How to highlight current menu without a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a table that contains organisation's name which is generated the list  from database.

```js
$resultorg1 = mysql_query("select * from organisations where type_role like '%,1,%' and display_countries like '%,$country,%' and dissolved='' order by short_name") or die("Error ".__LINE__);

$oname = mysql_result($resultorg1, $org, "short_name");

$orgtext1 = "";

$orgtext1. = "<table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' border='0' width='280' onclick='getOrgPage($oid)'><tr><td width=238 height=20 align='left' valign='top'><div id='org_name'><font class='country_menu_orgname'>".$oname.
"</font></div></td>";

$orgtext1. = "</tr></table>\n";
```

and when click on each table will do onclick function [getOrgPage]

```js
function getOrgPage(oid) {
  document.getElementById('country_rep_body').innerHTML = "<center><br><br><Br><Br><font style='font-size:14px;color:#999999'>..... Retrieving Data .....</font></center>";
  //urlo = "get_country_orgs.php?oid="+oid;
  urlo = "get_country_orgs.php?oid=" + oid + "&ttype=9&country=<? echo $country; ?>";
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    reqo = new XMLHttpRequest;
  } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    reqo = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  if (reqo) {
    reqo.onreadystatechange = getOrgPageResp;
    reqo.open("GET", urlo, true);
    reqo.send(null);
  } else {
    alert("Your browser does not support XMLHttpRequest technology!");
    doesNotSupport = false;
  }
  return false;
}

function getOrgPageResp() {
  if (reqo.readyState == 4) {
    if (reqo.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById('country_rep_body').innerHTML = reqo.responseText;
      //resetSumo();
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

to show content on the right side like this

[image]

**Question**

How can I highlight current section ?(current table that I clicked) 
Do I have to apply a div in each table(each organisation name)?

just have no idea how to do that without a href link style.

Thanks.

Comment: you can simply create a CSS class and add it to the element on click

Comment: remove existing active class and add active class to clicked element